# send data back to previous controller from the second controller it displays Google autocomplete search Places

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete

Hello I have a button in FirstVC and in SecondVC I have a search box on navigationBar which is Google Autocomplete search bar in which user types something and it shows the places. What I want is when user clicks the button and secondVC comes, as soon user selects the place, the firstVC should show up with the data selected on secondVC without user presses any action Button.

Before implementing Google autocomplete, I was showing locations from database in TableView and I was redirecting user to first controller by writing some code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  and everything was working fine. its not working here. I'll Paste my code here of what I am doing right now

**FirstVC:**

```
class AddRequestTableViewController:GooglePlacesViewControllerDelegate{


func country(place: GMSPlace!) {
        dismissKeyboard()

         print("Place name: ", place.name)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {


            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as!   GooglePlacesViewController

            destination.delegate = self



        }

}
```

**SecondVC**

```
protocol GooglePlacesViewControllerDelegate {
    func country(place: GMSPlace!,departureOrArrivalSegue:Int)
}
class GooglePlacesViewController: UIViewController {
     var delegate : GooglePlacesViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    var resultView: UITextView?
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var placesClient : GMSPlacesClient?
    var departureOrArrivalSegue:Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        // locationManager.delegate = self
        //locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()


        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar

        // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
        // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera

        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()


        run()


    }


    func run(){

        placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({
            (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let placeLicklihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {

                let  place = placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first! as GMSPlaceLikelihood
                if let place : GMSPlaceLikelihood = place {
                    print("place is \(place.place.formattedAddress)")
                }
            }
        })

    }



}

// Handle the user's selection.
extension GooglePlacesViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!,
                           didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace!) {
        searchController?.active = false
        // Do something with the selected place.
        print("Place name: ", place.name)
        print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
        print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)
        print("cordinates are \(place.coordinate)")
        delegate.country(place)

    }

    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.description)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate method is:

```
func country(place: GMSPlace!,departureOrArrivalSegue:Int)
```

but you only called:

```
delgate.country(place)
```

Are you not recieving a compiler error? There should be another argument for your delegate call.

Also your 'GooglePlacesViewController' has not declared itself a delegate for the 'resultsViewController'. You called:

```
resultsViewController?.delegate = self
```

So your 'GooglePlacesViewController' should look something like this:

```
class GooglePlacesViewController: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
```

How you aren't recieving compiler errors is beyond me. Are you using nano?

Comment: oh I am sorry It was a typo error here.. just consider one parameter... and other then that if I use this ResultsViewControllerDelegate  I am getting an error it says use of undeclared type..

Comment: Well that is not the actual delegate name. IDK what it is but you will have to find it. Try 'option' clicking on the line that says: 'resultsViewController?.delegate = self' in xcode. That will bring up the delegate type and insert that instead of the 'ResultsViewControllerDelegate'

Comment: Quick Google Search.... Replace it with 'GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate'